# Adding additional pages for a Custom Post Type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type called "Courses".

Wordpress automatically adds the following urls for "Courses":

- http://example.com/course/: **The Archive Page (i.e. archive-course.php)**
- http://example.com/course/course-name/: **The course page (i.e. single-course.php)**

However I wish to add a few more additional pages:

- http://example.com/course/course-name/enquiry/: **An enquiry page for each course**
- http://example.com/course/course-name/demo/: **A demo page for some courses, if they satisfy a certain condition**

The issue is I am unsure of the "proper" way how to add these pages. The way I am doing it now is like so:

```
function create_post_types() {
    // ...add custom post types ...

    add_rewrite_rule("course/([^/]+)/enquiry/?$",
        'index.php?post_type=course&course=$matches[1]&enquiry=true', 'top');

    add_rewrite_rule("course/([^/]+)/demo/?$",
        'index.php?post_type=course&course=$matches[1]&demo=true', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types' );

function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "enquiry";
    $vars[] = "demo";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

And then in "single-course.php" I added the following if statements:

```
if (get_query_var('enquiry')) {
    // enquiry page code
} else if (get_query_var('demo')) {
    // Demo Page code
} else {
    // Single course page code
}
```

However, the way I did it feels more like a hack and does not feel like the proper Wordpress way of doing it. Hence, it does not work well with other plugins such as "Yoast SEO Plugin" which does not recognise my additional pages in it's XML sitemaps. I assume a similar issue will occur in regards to breadcrumbs.

What is the best practice or better way for adding additional pages for a custom post type?

**Optional Question:** Also what would be a suitable way to implement the demo page (as this requires checking the course satisfies a certain condition via `get_field('online_course') == True`.

Comment: I think your method *is* the most correct way to do it... However if wordpress SEO by yoast, inclusion in automatic sitemaps etc. are a priority, then I think the most *compatible* solution would be to actually create the extra pages as child pages (automatically of course). Conditional demopage should just return a 404 if that particular course has no demo - if you create "physical" child pages it's a no-brainer how you do it: don't create that child page. If you stick with your current method do the check on the page itself and return 404.

Comment: Note: you'll need quite a few action hooks to make sure the child pages mirror the parents status at all times, and is not accidentally deleted manually (if that could be a concern)... in other words it'll be **way** more "hackish" than your current solution - but I still think it would be more compatible.

Comment: why not add pages as children of you CPT?

Comment: I agree with @Mikk3lRo, use rewrites to create these type pages. Do you really want to index contact forms anyway?

Comment: No in this case I don't want to index contact forms, but I just want to know the PROPER way of doing when I DO want to index the pages

Comment: @Mark I never even heard of that. Can you explained how to do that or a link to a reference (sorry I tagged the wrong person last time)

Comment: It's not a nice solution, and it would be extremely complicated (for it to be reliable), so I won't spend time putting together a complete example. But you can create, delete, update posts programatically (google it, I'm on my iphone writing this), and you can hook pretty much any change to your custom post type posts to update status etc. of the children when needed. So it's definitely possible in theory... but the more I think about it the worse of an idea I think it would be in reality...

Comment: Err. Sorry, I thought your comment was directed at me, for some reason it popped up with a big fat red dot in my inbox :p

Comment: That was my bad cause I put the wrong name down

Answer (score 0):

declare the custom post type

**in your functions.php:**

```
$labelsCourse = array(
        'name' => 'Course',
        'singular_name' => 'Course',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Course',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Course',
        'new_item' => 'New Course',
        'view_item' => 'View Course',
        'search_items' => 'Search Courses',
        'not_found' => 'No courses found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No courses found in Trash.'
    );
register_post_type('course', array(
    'labels' => $labelsCourse,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'has_archive' => 'course',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'course', 'with_front' => false ),
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'page-attributes')
));
```

Then in your admin add a new course titled: *"course-name"* then add another new course titled: *"demo"*.

Then in your single-course.php you can add a conditional statement to call the child pages.

Comment: This seems even more hackish than my way, as "demo" is not a course but just another page to "course". It will also mean I will have to add a demo to EVERY course. Fair idea though.